# PSET6 DNA: Code only computes longest number of consecutive repeats for one STR sequence

Tags: python, cs50

I have written a code to count the longest number of consecutive repeats of specific DNA substring sequences (taken from a csv file) in a long string of DNA (taken from a text file)...or so I thought. While my code can correctly count the longest number of consecutive repeats for the last DNA substring in a dictionary of substrings, it fails to do so for the other DNA substrings preceding it. I have tried multiple things to fix my code but nothing works. How do I count the longest number of consecutive repeats for each DNA substring and not just one? Any advice welcome! Here is my code:

```
import sys
import csv

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Wrong number of files. Enter correct command-line arguments")
    exit(1)

with open (sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    database_reader = csv.reader(f)
    strlist = next(database_reader)[1:]
    print(strlist)

    dna = open(sys.argv[2], "r")
    sequence_dna = dna.read()
    print(sequence_dna)

    long_str = {}

    for item in strlist:
        long_str[item] = 0

    for key in long_str:
        i = 0
        run = 0
        long_run = 0
        while i < len(sequence_dna):
            if sequence_dna[i:i+len(key)] == key:
                run += 1
                if run > long_run:
                    long_run = run
                i += len(key)
            elif sequence_dna[i:i+len(key)] != key:
                if run > long_run:
                    long_run = run
                run = 0
                i += 1
    long_str[key] = long_run
    print(long_str)

    for row in database_reader:
        individual = row[0]
        values = [int(value) for value in row[1:]]
        if values == long_str:
            print(individual)
            break
        elif values != long_str:
            print("No match")
            break
```

Comment: Oh I missed what exactly you wanted to know. Maybe indent `long_str[key] = long_run` to be assigned to all the keys in the for loop. Now, its just being assigned the last key and count.

Comment: Omg wow, I cannot believe I didn't consider that the indent could have been the problem. Thank you! Your suggestion worked!

Comment: I may be wrong, but the last for loop seems to have problems. `if values == long_str:` is checking for equality between a list of ints against `long_str` which is a dictionary. I don't think that the if statement could be true because of this. Maybe could write: `if values == long_str.values()`, but I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: That should read instead I think `if values == list(long_str.values())`

Comment: Thank you. I did that, but now the problem is that I keep getting no match when I compare the dictionary values against data in a csv file, when I am actually supposed to get a match. I printed the `long_str` dictionary and I see that it prints out three times: one after each iteration for each key. I think that's why I am getting no match as output. Now I need help figuring out a way to just get the last iteration

Comment: I figured it out! It was another indentation problem. I think that's my flaw unfortunately. But I also deleted the `elif` condition, and used `else` instead. And I aligned it with the `for` loop and now my code works perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it. Do your answers agree with the answers given with this exercise? Just asking because I don't know if they do. (I updated the post (below) to show that I got answers agreeing with the correct ones).

Answer (score 0):

The following changed code should work. The way it is now, if the first person (or following persons) to check is not equal to the sequence file input, the loop will exit instead of checking all until a match is found (or no match). The `elif` is wrong here.

```
found = False
for row in database_reader:
    individual = row[0]
    values = [int(value) for value in row[1:]]
    if values == list(long_str.values()):
        found = True
        print(individual)
        break

if found == False:
    print('no match')
```

When I ran my version, (not given here),it agreed with the answers given for this exercise.

```
C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/small.csv sequences/1.txt
Bob

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/small.csv sequences/2.txt
no match

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/small.csv sequences/3.txt
no match

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/small.csv sequences/4.txt
Alice

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/5.txt
Lavender

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/6.txt
Luna

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/7.txt
Ron

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/8.txt
Ginny

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/9.txt
Draco

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/10.txt
Albus

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/11.txt
Hermione

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/12.txt
Lily

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/13.txt
no match

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/14.txt
Severus

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/15.txt
Sirius

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/16.txt
no match

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/17.txt
Harry

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/18.txt
no match

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/19.txt
Fred

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv sequences/20.txt
no match

C:\Old_Data\python\Harvard\dna>python dna2.py databases/large.csv
Usage: python dna2.py <databases/database> <sequences/seq>
```